# The insertion point is skipping a line

Tags: java

This is my first week of coding and I am unsure of why when I go to ask "Do you enjoy life", it forces me to type the answer on the next line.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class messing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Your Name: ");
        String name = keyboardInput.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How old are you: ");
        int age = keyboardInput.nextInt();
        System.out.println(name + " you are " + age + "?" + " Do you enjoy life: " );

        String enjoy = keyboardInput.next();
        System.out.print(enjoy + "?");
   }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code as text and not as image

Answer (score 1):

This is because the line of code that displays the question (line 13) uses the `System.out.println()` function, which, in addition to the text displayed, appends a newline character. This sends any further text onto the next line in the console. Replacing the function with the `System.out.print()` function removes this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using `System.out.println` when asking the user if they enjoy life.

Simply change the function to `System.out.print` like the rest so you can input your answer in the same line.

```java
System.out.print(name + " you are " + age + "?" + " Do you enjoy life: " );
```